# Simple form not saving nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a User model. Using Devise. When I create a user I want to create a venue through a nested form.

I swapped to simple_form.

I am sure that it is a simple error and something that I have missed

I am getting unpermitted params on the venue and it's driving me nuts, please help

Models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :masqueradable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :omniauthable

  has_one_attached :avatar
  has_person_name
  has_many :venues, inverse_of: :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :venues

end

    class Venue < ApplicationRecord
        belongs_to :user
    end
```

Controllers

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_action :masquerade_user!

  protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name, venue_attributes: [:name, :id]])
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name, :avatar])
    end
end

class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  # before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
     @user = User.new
     @user.venues.build
  end

class VenuesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_venue, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /venues or /venues.json
  def index
    @venues = Venue.all
  end

  # GET /venues/1 or /venues/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /venues/new
  def new
    @venue = Venue.new
  end

  # GET /venues/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /venues or /venues.json
  def create
    @venue = Venue.new(venue_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @venue.save
        format.html { redirect_to @venue, notice: "Venue was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @venue }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @venue.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /venues/1 or /venues/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @venue.update(venue_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @venue, notice: "Venue was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @venue }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @venue.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /venues/1 or /venues/1.json
  def destroy
    @venue.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to venues_url, notice: "Venue was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_venue
      @venue = Venue.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def venue_params
      params.require(:venue).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

the error I get is

Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2021-08-05 09:02:08 +1000
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"name"=>"test test", "email"=>"test@test.com", "venue"=>{"name"=>"test"}, "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Unpermitted parameter: :venue

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <%= f.input :name, autofocus: false, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Full name" %>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <%= f.input :email, autofocus: false, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Email Address" %>
      </div>
      
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :venue do |v| %>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <%= v.input :name, autofocus: false, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Full name" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <%= f.input :password, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Password' %>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <%= f.input :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Confirm Password' %>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3 d-grid">
      <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="text-center">
      <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Comment: Could you share the form please?

Comment: @Clara added the form, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a simple pluralization error. Your model `has_many :venues` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :venues` so you need to use the plural `:venues` in your form:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :venues do |v| %>
  <div class="mb-3">
      <%= v.label :name %>
      <%= v.input :name, autofocus: false, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And you need to whitelist `venues_attributes`:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name, venues_attributes: [:name, :id]])
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name, :avatar])
end
```

Comment: On a side note - use actual labels. Placeholders are horrible from an accessibility and useability standpoint.

Comment: Appreciate That Max